# Prevent Redux actions performance on client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React/Redux/SSR app. Right now my app works as follows:

1. A user visits some url, browser sends request to Frontend server (Node.js)
2. Frontend server gets all necessary data for this url from Backend server (Ruby) and build html then responds to user's browser with filled `window._PRELOADED_STATE_` with appropriated Redux store's state
3. User's browser renders received html and runs bundle.js script which is React app. It uses filled before `window._PRELOADED_STATE_` to initialize app (at this time actions run again)

I want to prevent Redux actions performance on the first rendering on client because all is done on the server already.

What I have tried: on client after the first rendering I delete `window._PRELOADED_STATE_` and run actions if `window._PRELOADED_STATE_` exists only. But deleting of `window._PRELOADED_STATE_` performs before app initialization so actions run anyway.

How can I get desired behaviour? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: @Aruna it's quite inconvenient because app is spread to several files: app.jsx - express server, index.jsx - whole app entrypoint, store.js for configuring store, App.jsx - main component and other files like actions, reducers. What concrete file do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the opportunity to use React in dev mode?

In dev mode React will complain if it's not able to match the SSR code with the front-end code. It looks to me that you can have a similar situation.

If that's not the case, which are the actions that run at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, I can run app in dev mode. There are no any problems with the markup, it's the same on both sides. Look, I have a page with projects list. On this page there is Projects component which run loadProjects action (here is request to backend) to update projects in store. On server side I skip actions because I have to load all data at first and then createStore with this data. Problem is redundant requests on projects page at first time (I got data already on server). But when I leave and visit projects page again I want to run action to get actual projects data. I hope I explain clearly

Comment: Mmm so on the server side you're not performing the action because you're injecting data via the createStore, got that. Now the browser instead it's not skipping that action and it's contacting directly Ruby to get the data. Why do you need the action at all? You're always composing the page in the SSR part

Comment: SSR is used to render the first page only. It can be /projects or /projects/:id or something else, it does not matter. After that user's browser interacts with backend directly to get actual data

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to understand what's the problem :(